# Installation of Wpasupplicant failed on ubuntu 16.04 server, problems with libnl-3-dev

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I am trying to install the latest Wpa_Supplicant on Ubuntu 16.04 server from the official website. According to http://deployingradius.com/scripts/eapol_test/ I uncommented `CONFIG_EAPOL_TEST=yes` and run `make eapol_test` but I get failed:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1613: recipe for target 'eapol_test' failed
make: *** [eapol_test] Error 1
```

However, when I did the same but using Ubuntu 14.04 server, everything is ok!

I realized that the package `libnl-dev`resolves the problem of  `**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl**` for ubuntu14.04. However, the Ubuntu 16.04 does not have `libnl-dev` in his repository, instead of It has `libnl-3-dev`, but `wpa_supplicant` failed when I run `make eapol_test`.

Could anyone help me install wpa_supplicant on ubuntu 16.04 plz?, I am trying run everything on ubuntu 16.04 and not on ubuntu 14.04.

Thank you in advance,
Javier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the following:

- install the package `libnl-genl-3-dev`
- in the .config file uncomment the following (2nd) line:

  `# Use libnl 3.2 libraries (if this is selected, CONFIG_LIBNL20 is ignored)
  CONFIG_LIBNL32=y`

I could then link the target correctly, because it then used "-lnl-3" instead of "-lnl"